# Spring security not authorised is not setting referer

Tags: java, spring-security

I have an older Spring Security 3 application.  When I go to a url that is restricted in some way,  ie,  isAuthenticated, like this:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/details/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

it redirects me to the login url as expected.  However when I try and access the referrer in the header like this:  (This is the first line in my login page controller)

```
request.getHeader("Referer");
```

I get null.

I need to be able to redirect back to /details/  once logged in.

How would I do this?

Comment: Have you tried [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032166/3710490](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032166/3710490)?

Comment: That is not working,  I get a null when trying to get that header in my controller.

Comment: Spring Security remembers the url visited in its `RequestCache` automatically.  Are you bypassing the filter chain's built-in support for processing the authentication credentials? Maybe post to github a simplified sample - I'd be happy to see if I can figure out a PR.